# Google Map V3: Loading a route (JSON string) from a mysql database onto a map using php, javascript and ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

I'm attempting to retrieve and load a series of waypoints from a mysql database onto a map using ajax, javascript and php. The route is stored in the database using a JSON string.

This is the javascript function that is called (the parameter is the id of the route to be loaded, as there are many routes in the database):

```
function fetchdata(id) {
        var routeID = id;
        var jax = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        jax.open('POST','process.php');
        jax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        jax.send('command=fetch&rid='+routeID);
        jax.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(jax.readyState==4) {     
                try {
                    setroute(JSON.parse(jax.responseText));
                }
                catch(e){
                    alert(e);
                }
            }
        }
```

The php file it calls contains this if statement to seperate save and fetch commands:

```
//Retrieving the route from the database.
if($_REQUEST['command']=='fetch') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Route WHERE route_id='$id'";
    if(!($res = mysql_query($query))) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    else {
        $rs = mysql_fetch_array($res,1);
        die($rs['waypoints']);  
    }           
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that when the value is passed back to ajax/javascript it is just reporting an "Object Error" and is not being parsed by the JSON.parse() method. I'm not if I'm passing the wrong type of object back to ajax, but I have tried converting it to a strong also.

Any help on solving this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you show me the JSON string returned by the AJAX call? (eg Use Firebug's net panel or similar to show the JSON.) I suspect that somehow the JSON is getting corrupted, not returned properly.

Comment: Using Firebug it says that this is the response:
{"start":{"lat":51.27454,"lng":1.0773599999999987},"end":{"lat":51.27688000000001,"lng":1.074389999999994},"waypoints":[]}

Comment: I ran `console.log(JSON.parse('yourJSONstring');` in firebug and I ran into encoding issues that meant it would not parse. The problem was that JSON.parse was seeing `0000000â€Œâ€‹1,"lng":` where it should see `00000001,"lng":`. If that's happening at your end, there's your problem. MySQL is returning text that has borked the character encoding somewhere along the line.

Comment: ps simply deleting and re-typing the code as it 'should' appear allowed the JSON to parse properly.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, but I've tried retyping the JSON string, but it's still throwing an "Object Error".

Comment: Ah I've just tried changing JSON.parse(string) to eval('(' + string ')') and it seems to be working now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's great - just remember the additional security concerns when you use eval. That does suggest that JSON.parse has a problem with encoding being given to it, as eval proves the syntax is right. I was going to suggest you open a blank page containing only 
'<script>
     console.log(JSON.parse('{"start":
          {"lat":51.27454,"lng":1.0773599999999987},"end":
               {"lat":51.2768800000000‌1,"lng":1.074389999999994},"waypoints":
[]}'));

</script>' (what I did) to see if you get the encoding error that I saw (copy your own JSON into the code, not mine).